# CountDistinct() is counting value twice when grouped in SSRS

Tags: sql, reporting-services

```
-- Sample data.
declare @Table1 as Table ( RegisterId Int Identity, UnitId Int, DateRegistered date);
declare @Table2 as Table ( Id Int Identity, RegisterId Int, Rep1 int, Rep2 int, DateCreated Date );
declare @Table3 as Table ( UnitId int Identity, UnitName varchar(40), SquadName varchar(40))

insert into @Table1 ( UnitId, DateRegistered ) 
values
  ( 1, '20160115' );
insert into @Table2 ( RegisterId, Rep1, Rep2, DateCreated ) 
values
  ( 1, 3, 4, '20160122' ), ( 1, 10, 4, '20160129' ), ( 1, 32, 45, '20160210' );
insert into @Table3 ( UnitName ) 
values
  ( 'Tango', 'West' ), ( 'Lima', 'West' ), ( 'Foxtrot', 'West' );


SELECT t3.UnitName
       , t2.RegisterId
       , t2.DateCreated
       , t2.Rep1 + t2.Rep2 as 'TotalReps'
       , DateName(month, t2.DateCreated) as 'Month'
       , DateName(year, t2.DateCreated) as 'Year'
FROM @Table1 t1
INNER JOIN @Table2 t2 ON t1.RegisterId = t2.RegisterId
INNER JOIN @Table3 t3 ON t1.UnitId = t3.UnitId
```

Building a report in SSRS, the above is my query. Report parameters are a start date, enddate and UnitId(s).

In the report I have 3 Row Groups - Month, Year, SquadName. In the report I am using the TotalReps for totalreps, CountDistinct(Field!RegisterId.Value) for the ConfirmedRegisters and Count(Field!RegisterId.Value) for CheckIn.  THe TOTALs are just SUMS of the expressions, SUM(CountDistinct(Field!RegisterId.Value)).

The report shows like:

```
           TotalReps    ConfirmedRegisters  CheckIns
WEST

  2016

    Jan

              21            1            2

    Feb

              77            1            1

TOTAL         98            1            3
```

Some definitions.  A ConfirmedRegister means the Id exists in Table1 AND Table2.  A Checkin is just a count of Table2 Ids.  So to be a checkin, there must be a row in Table2 and a ConfirmedREgister can ONLY BE COUNTED ONCE, regardless of the number of checkins and when they happen.  So if a Table1 register occurs in Jan 2016 and there are checkins off the registerid in Jan and Feb 2016 as our test data suggests, the report should show a zero in the ConfirmedRegisters columns for Feb because the RegisterId was counted in Jan.

Should be:

```
           TotalReps    ConfirmedRegisters  CheckIns
WEST

  2016

    Jan

              21            1            2

    Feb

              77            0            1

TOTAL         98            1            3
```

Notice the TOTAL Confirmed Registers is showing correct, I guess because it is totalling the whole date range.  But The MONTHLY totals are incorrect for the CONFIRMEDREGISTERS columns because it is counting RegisterID for Jan and Feb where it should only count the Jan and put nothing or 0 for Feb.

Not sure if I need do fix this in the query or the report.

Comment: You cannot fix this in the report. The `CountDistinct` will do a distinct count within each group it is in. Try doing something in the query, like you suspected you might.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by using a CTE with a windowing function (row_number() over(partition ...) to mimic a 'First()' type function so I could then count the first occurrence of each RegisterId from Table2.